# Android: saving data into SQLite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to save some data from editText to the SQLite database which is based on my Android device (and it should be based only on devices)...
so I created `DatabaseHelper` class and I creating database there, here is code of this file:

```
package ru.vladimir.droid_spy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "phones";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONES ="phone_number";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "trusted_phone.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //create database
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_PHONES + " text not null);";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

and then I want to save some data from my Activity with this code:

```
try 
{
    DatabaseHelper DBhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getBaseContext());
    //put DB in write mode
    SQLiteDatabase db = DBhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    //put variables
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID, 1);
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PHONES, txt_phone.getText().toString());

    //insert variables into DB
    long query = db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    //close DB
    db.close();
} 
catch(Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println("Error: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

but when I saw LogCat logs, there was an error message:

```
07-27 00:04:50.463: E/SQLiteDatabase(15075): Error inserting phone_number=WEB
07-27 00:04:50.463: E/SQLiteDatabase(15075): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table phones has no column named phone_number: , while compiling: INSERT INTO phones(phone_number) VALUES (?)
```

I think that this error is telling about that I do not create a column in my database, but how I can't create it, if I create this column in `CREATE_DATABASE` variable?

Comment: `Clear Data` and try again. Maybe you had a bad earlier version of your DB still around?

Comment: @323go and how I can clear data?

Comment: Settings/Applications/[your app name], tap `Clear Data`

Comment: @323go ok, it helped! thanks... but one more question.. how now I can see what is inserted into my DB?

Comment: If you're running on emulator, you can directly access the db through the DDMS. If not, you'll have to dump it from your app through a SELECT statement, or copy the DB file to SD card.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but could it be that you ran the app before with with a different table structure? Since your database version is still 1, `onUpgrade()` gets never called. Neither does `onCreate()` because the db already exists. Either increase the db version, or uninstall and re-install the app  to be sure that the db gets newly created.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Sqlitedatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public Sqlitedatabase(Context context) {
      super(context, "DoctorDatabase.db", null, 1);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      String tableEmp = "create table Doctor(Name text,Number text)";
      db.execSQL(tableEmp);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  }

  public void insertData(DocotorInformation doctor) {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put("Name", doctor.getName()); // Contact Name
      values.put("Number", doctor.getNumber()); // Contact Phone Number

      // Inserting Row
      db.insert("Doctor", null, values);
      db.close(); // Closing database connection
  }


  public ArrayList<DocotorInformation> getAllContacts() {
      ArrayList<DocotorInformation> contactList = new ArrayList<DocotorInformation>();
      // Select All Query
      String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM Doctor";

      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

      // looping through all rows and adding to list
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          do {
            DocotorInformation contact = new DocotorInformation();
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(0));
            contact.setNumber(cursor.getString(1));

            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
    }
}
```